# How to stop a message pop up confirm if validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a confirmation message box that appears when a person clicks on the save button, it just simply asks them to confirm they want to save, however this pops up even if all the validation is failed, is there a way to only show the message box if all validation been successful

```
<p>
        <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.buttonSaveMark}"  icon ="ui-icon-disk" update="displayMark :growl" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" /> 
    </p>
    <p:dialog header="Confirm Mark" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fold" hideEffect="fold">  
        <h:panelGrid id="displayMark" columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
            <h:outputText value="Mark to be submitted: " />  
            <h:outputText value="#{selectedValue}"/>  
            <p:commandButton id="save"
                             value="#{bundle.buttonSave}"
                             actionListener ="#{markingBean.editMark}"
                             update="Navigation :growl"
                             icon="ui-icon-disk"
                             oncomplete="PF('nav').show()"/>
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:dialog>  

    <p:dialog header="Navigation" widgetVar="nav" showEffect="fold" hideEffect="fold">  
        <h:panelGrid id="Navigation" columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
            <h:outputText value="Return to this project's marking page: " />  
            <p:button id="go"
                      value="#{bundle.buttonProjMark}"
                      outcome ="/lecturer/marking/marking-index.xhtml?edit_id=#{markingBean.markToEdit.id}"
                      icon="ui-icon-clipboard"/>
            <h:outputText value="Return to staff homepage: " />  
            <p:button id="staffHome"
                      value="#{bundle.buttonStaffHome}"
                      outcome ="/index"
                      icon="ui-icon-home"/>
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:dialog>
```

that is the button and then the confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update tha Navigation dialog from Java code with

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("Navigation");
```

Also add a callBackParam from java code:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("showDialog",true);
```

Add the above codes to your `markingBean.editMark` action. If the validation fails, your action won't be called, so the callbackParam won't be added, and this way the dialog won't appear.

On the client side should create a js function which handles the request complete:

```
function handle(args) {
    if (data != null && data.showDialog) {
        PF('nav').show()
    }
}
```

And on the button:

```
oncomplete="handle(args);"
```

Comment: If this solution is suitable for you, than please accept the anwser. So others will know it is a closed question. Thanks.